# How can I find the first post in a category that has a featured image and then return the get_the_post_thumbnail()?

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have a function that I thought should find the first article with a featured image in it, and then return that image. Not sure if this is the best way to go about it, as it's giving me a 502 Bad Gateway...

```
function get_category_post($cat_id){
        $finished = false;
        $postcount = 0;
        $post_args = array(
            'numberposts' => 1,
            'category' => $cat_id,
            'fields' => 'ids'
        );
        $posts = get_posts($post_args);
        while ( $finished != true ) {
            if ( has_post_thumbnail($posts[$postcount]) ) {
                $postthumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($posts[$postcount], $size = 'thumbnail');
                $finished = true;
            }
            $postcount++;
        }
        return $postthumb;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ID of the featured image is stored under the meta key `_thumbnail_id`, so we can do a query for a single post that has this key:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id',
    'cat' => $cat_id
);
$latest_thumb = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $latest_thumb->have_posts() )
    return get_the_post_thumbnail( $latest_thumb->post->ID );
```

Comment: This one worked perfectly, and it's simpler than my previous structure. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

As discussed over [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-the-post-only-if-thumbnail-is-set-up?replies=17), you need to use the `meta_key` parameter in your `$post_args` array, like this:

```
$post_args = array(
    'category'    => $cat_id,
    'fields'      => 'ids',
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'meta_key'    => '_thumbnail_id'
);
```

I'm not sure a `while` loop is needed for this. I would probably rewrite your function like this (haven't tested yet):

```
function get_category_post($cat_id){

    $post_args = array(
        'category'    => $cat_id,
        'fields'      => 'ids',
        'numberposts' => 1,
        'meta_key'    => '_thumbnail_id'
    );

    $post_id = get_posts( $post_args );

    return get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id[ 0 ], 'thumbnail' );
}
```